# org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.8:run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, java-11

I was trying to build a spring boot project. Below is pom.xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.8</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>handling-form-submission</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>handling-form-submission</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-hadoop</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Also, Java version installed on my windows PC is below:

```
 PS > java -version
java version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.10+8-LTS-162, mixed mode)
```

I am trying to run the spring boot application using following command: `.\mvnw -X spring-boot:run`

It shows following error
[image: error]
[image: mojo]

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I have seen other SO posts which says to check JAVA compiler version and pom.xml java version. I have checked that, it is both version 11. I have also checked all the dependency versions.

EDIT:

It shows following errors when run in debug mode:

```
    2021-07-23 10:31:23.564  INFO 2644 --- [           main] app.Main                                 : Starting Main using Java 11.0.10 on DESKTOP-D0HAG3S with PID 2644 (D:\optum_internship\handling-form-submission\target\classes started by Shruti Katpara in D:\optum_internship\handling-form-submission)
2021-07-23 10:31:23.570  INFO 2644 --- [           main] app.Main                                 : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-07-23 10:31:26.199  INFO 2644 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)  
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract scan(Lorg/apache/tomcat/Jar;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V of interface org.apache.tomcat.JarScannerCallback.
        at 
        ... 36 common frames omitted

2021-07-23 10:31:26.625  WARN 2644 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]    
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]  
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:437) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:934) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]  
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]   
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1318) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at app.Main.main(Main.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:940) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]    
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]      
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48] 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48] 
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]    
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]    
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48] 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48] 
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]    
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract scan(Lorg/apache/tomcat/Jar;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V of interface org.apache.tomcat.JarScannerCallback.
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:387) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:318) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:233) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) ~[jetty-runner-9.3.20.v20170531.jar:2.3.2]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:106) ~[jetty-runner-9.3.20.v20170531.jar:2.3.2]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103) ~[jetty-runner-9.3.20.v20170531.jar:2.3.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        ... 36 common frames omitted

2021-07-23 10:31:26.647  INFO 2644 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-07-23 10:31:26.695  WARN 2644 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2021-07-23 10:31:26.709  INFO 2644 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-07-23 10:31:26.878 ERROR 2644 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]   
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1318) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at app.Main.main(Main.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:159) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:940) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]    
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]  
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:437) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:934) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]  
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start 
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]    
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:940) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]    
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]      
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48] 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48] 
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]    
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]    
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48] 
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48] 
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]    
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner$TldScannerCallback does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract scan(Lorg/apache/tomcat/Jar;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V of interface org.apache.tomcat.JarScannerCallback.
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:387) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:318) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:233) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) ~[jetty-runner-9.3.20.v20170531.jar:2.3.2]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:106) ~[jetty-runner-9.3.20.v20170531.jar:2.3.2]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103) ~[jetty-runner-9.3.20.v20170531.jar:2.3.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.48.jar:9.0.48]
        ... 36 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:05 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-07-23T10:31:26+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.8:run (default-cli) on project handling-form-submission: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.8:run (default-cli) on project handling-form-submission: Application finished with exit code: 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Application finished with exit code: 1
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo.runWithForkedJvm (RunMojo.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.doRunWithForkedJvm (AbstractRunMojo.java:296)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:261)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo.execute (AbstractRunMojo.java:233)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start (BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute (WrapperExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main (MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Could you share the complete stacktrace behind that error? The `-X` should have provided you with much more relevant information than just the exit code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know its bit late to answer this question. I suspect , the application not started because of `AbstractMethodError` (`Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: ...`)

Just for try , exclude jetty-runner artifact from your huve-jdbc. like belowm

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-runner</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```